# Jenkins launch slave via execution of command on the master + The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: jenkins

Trying to start a slave on a remote machine from `Master` (local machine) using the `Jenkins` (launch slave via command line on Master)

```
ssh 10.1.18.135 java -jar D:/Jenkins/slave.jar
```

The slave.jar is present in the above path, It fails with this error:

> [07/01/13 14:16:11] Launching slave agent $ ssh 10.1.18.135 java -jar 
>       D:/Jenkins/slave.jar The system cannot find the file specified ERROR:
>       Unable to launch the slave agent for test123 : The system cannot find
>       the file specified java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "ssh":
>       CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified    at
>       java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)  at
>       hudson.slaves.CommandLauncher.launch(CommandLauncher.java:115)  at
>       hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer$1.call(SlaveComputer.java:230)  at
>       java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)   at
>       java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)     at
>       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>       java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the
>       file specified  at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)  at
>       java.lang.ProcessImpl.(Unknown Source)    at
>       java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)

Can someone help on this?

Answer (score 0):

"The system cannot find the file specified" refers to ssh, not slave.jar. Ensure you have a Windows ssh implementation installed and that the folder it resides in is present in your PATH environment variable.